# How to capture in lexical scope in a Clojure macro?

Tags: clojure, scope

In Common Lisp, I can define and use a macro that captures a variable from lexical scope, so that I can use it within a `let` form:

```
CL-USER> (defmacro plus9 () `(+ 9 woo))
PLUS9
CL-USER> (macroexpand '(plus9))
(+ 9 WOO)
T
CL-USER> (let ((woo 1)) (plus9))
10
```

However, when I define a similar macro in Clojure, it's looking for a definition of `woo` in the `user` namespace:

```
user=> (defmacro plus9 [] `(+ 9 woo))
#'user/plus9
user=> (macroexpand '(plus9))
(clojure.core/+ 9 user/woo)
user=> (let [woo 1] (plus9))

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: user/woo
```

Clearly I'm misunderstanding how scopes work in Clojure.  What's the correct way of achieving this macro with Clojure?

Comment: http://hubpages.com/technology/Unhygenic-anaphoric-Clojure-macros-for-fun-and-profit

Comment: Syntax quoting in Clojure is specifically designed to *avoid* collisions of quoted symbols names with lexically-scoped names, on the theory that these are typically unintended. As illustrated in the answer, you have to do extra work if that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm a macro noob, but how about

```
user=> (defmacro plus9 [] `(+ 9 ~'woo))
#'user/plus9
user=> (macroexpand '(plus9))
(clojure.core/+ 9 woo)
user=> (let [woo 1] (plus9))
10
```

Comment: Yeah. that's how you would capture a lexical binding in clojure. syntax-quote will qualify symbols according to the namespace, thus ensure hygiene. For that reason, `~'` is regarded as a code smell and idiomatically, you'd pass the symbol to be captured to the macro: ```(defmacro plus9 [sym] `(+ 9 ~sym)) , (let [x 1] (plus9 x))```